# How to extract numbers from the square braces in unix

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file with the following content.

```
abc.[1-3].title
simple.0[1-2].title
```

I need help to fetch the *output* as below using *sed* and *awk* commands.

```
abc.1.title
abc.2.title
abc.3.title
simple.01.title
simple.02.title
```

Comment: See [how I edited it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38659612/revisions). For code or sample files, you can select the lines and then press Ctrl+K to have it this fancy.

Comment: Sure, will follow this going forward.

Comment: Now it would be good to show what you have tried so far. Since you tagged with awk and sed, you must know a bit of it!

Comment: I'm bit familiar with sed and I'm finding myself tough in procuring the desired output. It would be great if it gets sorted out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sed is for simple substitution on individual lines, **that is all**. For anything else, e.g. your current problem, you should use awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[][]" }
{
    split($2,r,/-/)
    for (i=r[1]; i<=r[2]; i++) {
        print $1 i $3
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
abc.1.title
abc.2.title
abc.3.title
simple.01.title
simple.02.title
```

Read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Nice! I had played with `awk -F'[][-]' '{for (i=$2; i<=$3; i++) print $1 i $NF}' file` to prevent calling `split()`.

Comment: Regarding the first sentence--Nonsense!  Sed is also for making quines, and for playing code golf, and all sorts of other exciting, important activities!

Comment: @WilliamPursell You are correct. I forgot about the whole mental exercise aspect :-). I also suspect some sed scripts may control the weather...